# How to i add horizontal scrollbar in my Extjs Ext.Panel?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

my panel  width is long so when i load the page and minimize it i cant scroll left to view other thing.How to set it?

Comment: Can you post the code here? How do you scroll in a minimized browser?

Comment: i dont have the code right so i asked see got any idea from yours.^^

Comment: try to use "autoScroll : true" for the panel

Comment: i added but no use thank for telling

Answer (score 0):

use the [panel autoScroll](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.panel.Panel.html) property

```
autoScroll: true
```